# Certbot isn't creating the well-known folder (and how does it know where to do so anyway?)

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

Got certbot on my server. It's doing fine for all servers but for the WSGI-served Django application.

When I renew the certificates with `sudo certbot renew` it says the challenge doesn't complete. My webroot is `/srv/site`. Somehow, certbot knows it needs to create its challenges in `static/.well-known/acme-challenge`. (I wonder how it knows this, but it is indeed correct).

If I create this folder myself, and put a file "hello" there, I can retrieve it by going to [www.site.com/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/hello](http://www.site.com/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/hello). So why can't letsencrypt access the challenges it creates?

It seems that it's not creating this file. Not even the folder structure, despite running as root and being able to create whatever folders it pleases. I'm using `watch -n 0.5 ls -a /srv/site/static` to see if the .well-known folder gets made but it doesn't.

Why?

Full error:

```
user@host:/srv/site$ sudo certbot renew
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.tld.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for site.domain.tld
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Attempting to renew cert (site.tld) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.tld.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. site.domain.tld (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from https://site.domain.tld/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/yD-WpiQsGL1E_fvs2m-U6UDuHdLCh6shuJkmUdIzhXs [139.162.191.205]: "<!doctype html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons\" rel=\"stylesheet\">\n<". Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem (failure)
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you set the webroot as `/srv/site`. So the certbot will put the challenge at `/srv/site/.well-known/acme-challenge` and not at `/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/`. Also the certbot clears the challenges after the `certbot` command completes so you will not find the challenge files there. I think you need to change webroot to `static`.

Let me know if the solution worked or not. I really like to get feedback on my answers :)

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too, but the error message specifically states that it got an invalid response from http://site/static/.well-known... I understand certbot clears the challenge, which is why I am using `watch ls -a` to see if anything gets created, but nothing. Also not in the /srv/site folder.

Comment: Is certbot throwing that error? or you are seeing it in server logs? Can you paste the complete error here?

Comment: pasted in original post; the funny thing is I just tried running certbot renew again for lulz and it now just says my certificate isn't due for renewal. Which would mean at some point it succeeded anyway but I am absolutely sure it had been throwing errors at every attempt.